# useMutation with @tanstack/react-query doesn't refresh component

Tags: reactjs, tanstackreact-query

When i use useMutate from tanstack/react-query, my useQuery doesn't get updated.

```
const {
    isLoading,
    error: queryError,
    data: queryData,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["data"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      try {
        const dataRes = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/Interface");
        console.log(dataRes);
        return dataRes.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return null;
      }
    },
  });

  const { isPending, mutate, error, data } = useMutation({
    mutationKey: ["data"],
    mutationFn: async () => {
        const response = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:3000/Interface",
          postData,
          { headers },
        );
        return response.data;
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      console.log('onSuccess');
      return   queryClient.invalidateQueries(['data']);
    }
  });
```

Even if i try to return invalidateQueries with onSuccess, it doesn't work. I've checked others post but it didn't resolve my issue. Somehow, if i change tab in the browser, it got updated.

Thank you in advance for any answer.

I tried to return invalidateQueries with onSuccess on useMutation.

Comment: Your setup looks correct to me. Can you paste a complete example (and a codesandbox) for us to be able try it out?

Comment: "Somehow, if i change tab in the browser, it got updated." this is an unrelated feature of tanstack query. See `refetchOnWindowFocus`.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev i can't since it's a massive project and can't install dependencies in codesandbox. I tried to mutate with useEffect, refetch manually from the useQuery. Nothing seems to works. I think i should close this post.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev 
Edit: i make it refetch using useQuery work with the help of a button. But when i try to refetch using functions or mutation, it doesn't work.

Comment: To effectively answer questions, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Fork my example here: https://replit.com/@knyzorg/react-query-demo-so#src/App.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, `mutationKey` has no relation to `queryKey` - doesn't matter if they're the same, they have nothing to do with each other.

`invalidateQueries` is the correct thing to do, but it looks like you're using the wrong parameter, it should be an object with a property of `queryKey` instead of the queryKey itself.

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries({queryKey: ['data']});
```

See [the docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/guides/query-invalidation)